# Proof Verification: $c \mid ab$ implies $c \mid a$ or $c \mid b$, for $c$ prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers, divisibility

**Claim:** $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}, $ with $c$ prime. If $c \mid ab$ then $c \mid a$ or $c \mid b.$

**My Proposed Proof (Contrapositive):** Suppose $c\nmid a, c\nmid b$. So, $a = cd + r$ and $b = ce + q$, with $d,e,q, r \in \mathbb{Z}$. Note $q, r  \ne 0 \ne c.$ Next, $ab = c^2ed + cdq + cer + qr = c(ced + dq + er) + qr.$ Since $c$ is prime $qr \ne c$. Therefore $c\nmid ab$.

I am in an intro to proofs class, I just want to know if this proof is valid.

Comment: Note that you need to argue that $c$ doesn't divide $qr$, not just that $c\neq qr$.

Comment: @ColinAcker FYI, see [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

Comment: It may be interesting to compare with the proof in Euclid (book VII proposition 30).   https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/propVII30.html

Comment: To stress, this is incomplete as it stands.  All you conclude is that $c\,|\,ab\implies c\,|\,qr$ but why is that impossible?  Of course, if we knew the result, we'd know this was impossible...$c$ is a prime and $c$ can't divide either of $q,r$.  But that's ciruclar reasoning.

Comment: Hint:

Equivalently transform the statement into:
$$p\mid ab\ \mbox{and}\  p\nmid a\ \mbox{then}\  p\mid b.$$
Because then you have $ab=pm$ for some integer $m$ and $p,a$ would be coprime which implies that $p\lambda+a\mu=1$ for another integers $\lambda,\mu$.

Comment: What you proved is $\bmod c\!:\ a\equiv r,\ b\equiv q\Rightarrow ab\equiv rq,\,$ i.e. the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). You can use this to reduce this Euclid's Lemma to the case $\,0\le a,b < c,\,$ but you have not proved this reduced version. We already have most all known proofs of Euclid's Lemma in prior answers (so please don't duplicate them further in answers below).

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be an open-ended proof checking machine.